# Proving this inequality $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n < 3$

Tags: inequality

How would I prove this, particularly using a method using a geometric series and binomial coefficient.
I'm having trouble giving a reason for $(\star)$ especially.
This is what I did

For $n=1$, LHS = $(1+1)^1 = 2 < 3$ = RHS.
Thus, for $n=2$,
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \equiv {\large{\sum_{k=0}^n}} \begin{pmatrix}n \\ k \end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n^k} \\ = {\large{\sum_{k=0}^n}}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!n^k} \\ < \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \\ < \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \\ < \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(\frac{3}{2})^k} \qquad (\star)\\ = 3. $$

$(\star)$ since $k>2 > \frac{3}{2} \implies k! > 2 > \frac{3}{2}$ and $k! > (\frac{3}{2})^k$ for $k>2$.

I just know this to be true (the last step of raising 1.5 to the power $k$) by checking my calculator, but I don't see a reason why the factorial grows faster or becomes larger than the exponential.

Comment: Do you know what induction is?

Comment: Yup, but the course I'm doing right now introduces induction later on, so I think it preferred a purely inequality sort of proof.

Comment: $k! = k(k-1)...1.$ If $k > 2$ then the only term not greater than 3/2 is 1. So we just have to see if $k > 9/4.$

Comment: You still need to deal with the cases $k\leq 2$. The first three terms are $1+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{9}<1+1+\frac{1}{2}$. So you can't conclude $\star$ just yet.

Comment: But you do have $$1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\cdots < 1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$$

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010863/show-that-2-leq-left1-frac1x-rightx2-8 for a stronger statement.

Comment: Um. Just so you know, this is false for some negative $n$, such as $n=-1.5$. You may want to specify this in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at page 99 of [these notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), where I proved the sharper inequality $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\leq \frac{20}{7}$ by combining the AM-GM inequality with a creative telescoping idea.

Another possible approach, once it is proved that the sequence $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is increasing and convergent to $e$, it is to notice that $x(1-x)$ is non-negative and bounded by $\frac{1}{4}$ on $(0,1)$, hence

$$ 0\leq -1+\frac{3}{e} = \int_{0}^{1}x(1-x) e^{-x}\,dx \leq \frac{1}{4} $$
immediately leads to $e<3$.

The *layman's way* is just to recall that $e^{-x}$ is an entire function, hence $\frac{1}{e}$ is represented by a fast-convergent series:
$$ \frac{1}{e} = \frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}-\ldots $$
and due to the alternating signs:
$$ \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}<\frac{1}{e}< \frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!} = \frac{3}{8}$$
hence $e\in\left(\tfrac{8}{3},3\right).$

Comment: That is awesome.

Comment: Oh hey, the 2017 edition is out

Comment: Wow thanks for sharing that! Any other treasures you are hiding?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: and it is in English, finally. I guessed the approach *sooner or later, everyone has to learn Italian* does not really work.

Comment: Lol @JackD'Aurizio (cried a bit last year when I found out about that)

Comment: Mind I ask why you don't put it on your profile page?

Comment: @Ovi: I do not hide anything, my "creations" can be found on my site, www.matemate.it. *But*, it is in Italian (for now).

Comment: Guess I'll learn Italian.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: I should, but I cannot do that and preserve my *best of* collection, since I reached the maximum number of allowed characters :/ I should ask some moderator if there is a workaround for this issue.

Comment: Haha, if you wanted to, you could apply [tinyurl.com](http://tinyurl.com/), short and easy.

Comment: Another approach would be to use [goo.gl](https://goo.gl/)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: thanks for the suggestion, really appreciated. I will implement it tomorrow and save some space for linking my notes. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem :-) (its how I fit so many links in comments sometimes, and I originally learned of this because chat room descriptions are very limited)

Comment: Not meaning to bother, but the last line involving integrals on page 27 appears to be missing a few signs

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: thanks for pointing that out, I will check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64401/discussion-between-simply-beautiful-art-and-jack-daurizio).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this will work for $\frac{2}{3}$ but something similar does for $\frac{1}{2}$ ...

For $k \geq 2$ we have $ k! \geq 2^{k-1}$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} = 1+1+ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} < 2+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1} =2+ \frac{\frac{1}{2}} {1-\frac{1}{2}} =3.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: We need a proof of $ k! \geq 2^{k-1}$.

Comment: OK, easy inspection argument works.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly $k! = k(k - 1)...1.$ There are $k$ terms in there: $k, k - 1, k - 2, ..., 1.$ If $k > 2$ Then $(k-2)...(2) > (3/2)^{k - 2}$ because each term is greater than $3/2.$ So we just have to see if $k > (3/2)^2 = 9/4.$ Clearly, because $k$ is an integer and $k > 2$ we have that $k > 9/4.$

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Andrews pointed out in his comment, you need to show

$1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\cdots < 1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots$

Lemma: For all $n \ge 1$,
$\tag 1 \;2^n \le (n+1)!$
Proof
Let $I_n = \{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, and consider the symmetric group $S_{n+1}$ on $I_n \cup \{\hat x\}$. We claim that for any subset $J$ of $I_n$ we can associate a permutation $\sigma_J$ in $S_{n+1}$, and that the association is injective,

$\tag 2 \sigma_J = \sigma_K \Rightarrow J = K$

The empty set gets mapped to the identity permutation.
Any singleton, say $\{k\}$, would get mapped to the transposition $(k,\hat x)$.
Any other subset would get mapped to the natural cyclic permuation in $S_n$ that leaves $\hat x$ invariant.
(Example: $\{1,2,4,7\}$ in $I_{12}$ would map to $(1 \; 2\; 4\; 7)$ in $S_{12} \subset S_{13}$)
It is easy to see that this is injective, proving the claim.

The lemma has been proved since the number of subsets of $I_n$ is $2^n$ and the number of permutations in $S_{n+1}$ is $(n+1)!$.

You can check that the inequality (1) is strict when $n = 2$.

---

You can also verify (1) by inspection. The LHS has $n$ factors all equal to $2$, while the RHS also has $n$ factors all greater than or equal to $2$.

---

Another upper bound using elementary techniques:

## $e \lt 65/24 + 2^{-5} = 2.739583333$

The inspection method from above can be improved to show that

$\tag 3 \text{For all } n \ge 6 \text{, } \; 2^n \le (n-1)!$

So,

$1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24}+\frac{1}{120}+\cdots \lt$
$\quad (1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{24})+2^{-6}+2^{-7}+\cdots =$
$\quad (65/24)+2^{-5}(2^{-1}+2^{-2}+\cdots) = 65/24 + 2^{-5} $

You can continue this to get upper bounds arbitrarily close to $e$, the next step using

$\tag 4\text{For all } n \ge 8 \text{, } \; 2^n \le (n-2)!$